# Search bar by jquery ui autocomplete using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to add a search bar in my website, so I added jQUery UI autocomplete search and it works like a charm and the results are showing from the database. But, I need if the user clicks on a result from the list I want to redirect the user to that product page. This is the code in navigation.php:

```
<div id="search-div">
  <form action="#" id="form-search" method="POST" class="form-inline">
    <input id="language" type="text" placeholder="Search for a product" style="padding-left:15px;">
    </form>
</div>

<script>
$("#language").autocomplete({
  appendTo: $("#language").parent(),
  source: function(data, cb){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/tutorial/admin/parsers/ajax.php',
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        title: data.term
      },
      success: function(res){
      cb(res);
      }
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

And this is ajax.php code:

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tutorial/core/init.php';
$data = array();
if (!empty($_GET['title'])) {
  $title = strtolower(trim($_GET['title']));
  $sql = "SELECT title FROM products WHERE title LIKE '" .$title. "%'";
  $result = $db->query($sql);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($data, $row['title']);
  }
}
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
 ?>
```

The page that I want the user to be redirected to is **products.php?details=20** where 20 is the id of the product it is a GET method page. How to make the ability to redirect the product page based on the id if the user clicks on this product from the search list?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#language").autocomplete({
        source: function(data, cb){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/tutorial/admin/parsers/ajax.php',
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        title: data.term
      },
      success: function(res){
      cb(res);
      },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            window.location.href = ui.item.link;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select: function(event, ui) {
   doSearch(ui.item.title);
}

function doSearch(term) {
    window.location.href = 'Search.php?q=' + term;
}
```

search.php is your controller or contain business logic file.you can pass the query parameter as your need.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand your code. Can you please edit your code based on my code above? I need it based on the id of the product

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how to do it in jquery ui autocomplete this [OLD link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927224926/http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/MzsyY/1/) might be helpful.
But it's easy if you can use Twitter [Typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) instead of JQ UI.